# T-SQL Throw Exception within a transaction

Tags: .net, sql-server, t-sql

Today I was trying to write a transaction, within a stored procedure that in certain returns different numbers. It is necessary the C# code to know what exactly was the error. The problem is, that if the transaction is not completed it throws the same exception.

I could not throw exception inside the transaction, always was giving wrong syntax. I was trying with this pattern:

```
THROW 51000, 'The record does not exist.', 1;
```

Is it possible to make something like this:

```
BEGIN TRAN
  TRY

  IF...
     THROW ERROR 4;

  IF..
    THROW ERROR 2;

COMPLETE TRAN;
CATCH
   RETURN ERROR NUMBER;
```

I just need the specific number of the error returned from the stored procedure.

Can you please give me an example of that?

P.S. I forgot which is the version of our sql server, no I'm not in the office. It is either 2008 or 2012.

Comment: [Using a Return Code](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190778(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: [HOW TO: Return Errors and Warnings from a SQL Server Stored Procedure in ADO.NET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/321903)

Comment: Why don't you simply use a return code? Why throw only to hide the exception ?

Comment: Return causes the transaction to throw the same exception, because transaction is not completed.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following syntax:

```
BEGIN TRY
     BEGIN TRANSACTION
          IF ...  RAISERROR(51001, 16, 1)
          IF ...  RAISERROR(51002, 16, 1)
     COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
     DECLARE @ErrorNumber INT = ERROR_NUMBER();
     DECLARE @ErrorLine INT = ERROR_LINE();
     DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000) = ERROR_MESSAGE();
     DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT = ERROR_SEVERITY();
     DECLARE @ErrorState INT = ERROR_STATE();

     IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
          ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

     RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);
END CATCH
```

Error number should be greater then `50000`. You can add those with `sp_addmessage` procedure. `Throw` was introduced in `Sql Server 2012`. There are some differences. You can easily find them in `MSDN`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `RAISERROR` (read more in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms178592(v=sql.120).aspx)) instead of `THROW` (see [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677615.aspx)).

`THROW` will only re-throw an existing exception inside a `CATCH` block instead triggering a complete new exception. It was introduced in SQL Server 2012. The main usage for two functions which throw an error is quite simple. If an error occur inside a `TRY`, and you re-throw the error in your `CATCH` block using `RAISERROR` - as it was state of the art in 2008 - it may provide many useful information but the codeline in which the error occurred is shifted to the line where you raised the error using `RAISERROR`, not in the line where the error really occurred. Using `THROW` it will re-throw the error with all information, even the original line in which the error originally occurred.

Instead you can throw an own exception using this:

```
RAISERROR(N'Your Errormessage',16,1)
```

By the way, each error message used by `RAISERROR` will have a errormessage of 50000 or above. You can define your own error messages with their own id's (above 50000). If you defined your own message id, you can use `RAISERROR` to throw your user defined error like this:

```
RAISERROR(50001,16,1)
```

**Side info:** You can overload `RAISERROR` to parse values into your error message.

```
RAISERROR(N'A error occurred while iterating over row ID %i',16,1,@rowId)
```

Comment: The documentation for throw suggests it can be used to create new errors, not just throw an old one.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017
The article says "New applications should use THROW instead."